# Why isn't the fixed right col staying inside of the Position Relative Div?

Tags: html, css

please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qVHg8/1/

Why isn't the fixedRightCol being positioned at right:0 of the outer container div? Right now it's going outside of the container div which I don't want.

I could use position absolute, which puts the fixedRightCol in the right position but scrolls. I want the fixedRightCol to be fixed (no scroll).

so how can I get fixedRightCol position correctly and fixed on scroll?

Thanks

Comment: so just to follow up, you want the div to be fixed in the viewport, so it scrolls, but fixed the right edge of the parent div?

Comment: Alastair that is correct

Comment: Maybe I need to use two divs? One position absolute, and another fixed?

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working version. It uses Javascript & jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the green div to be fixed inside the red div, you need to use `position: absolute;`

http://jsfiddle.net/qVHg8/2/

`position: fixed;` fixes the element to the viewport, rather than the parent.

**EDIT:**

If you're able to use a bit of javascript & jQuery, then this will work with your dynamic margins:

```
$(function(){
    $('.fixedRightCol').css({right:  $('.container').offset().left});
});
```

What thats doing is setting the `right` CSS property to be the calculated `left` property of the container. As the margins are the same on both side (auto), then this will shit the red div to the correct position.

http://jsfiddle.net/qVHg8/4/ is a working example of this.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose that means I need a combo as that's what I'm trying to achieve. how is that possible?

Comment: @AnApprentice: Can you edit your question with what exactly you want to achieve? All the answers here answer your question as it currently is, but if you want it to do something else, then you need to specify that.

Comment: @AnApprentice: I've posted a comment on the original question.

Comment: I really appreciate this but not sure I want to resort to use JS to get this done. Seems like CSS should handle this. Take a look at the new facebook messages. When you view a message the right column works just like I'm trying to get done w/o JS?

Comment: Which right column are you referring to? The column of adverts?

Answer (score 1):

When you give something a position fixed, it breaks out of any divs it may be in.

Edit:
You could just do this:

```
.fixedRightCol{
    position: fixed;
    margin-left: 350px;
    width: 50px;
    background: green;
}
```

Use margin-left: 350px; for green box with NO right: 0px; or anything...

Comment: @AnApprentice: What's wrong with my answer? Works great without depending on the user having JavaScript turned on...

Answer (score 0):

i think you are meaning to use `position:absolute;`

Comment: I actually want it to be fixed. So I need something like absolute and fixed?

Comment: to affix something to another element is to use `position:absolute` relative to that element.  `position:fixed;` affixes the element to the window.